# Triple integral of $zx \sin(xy)$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am facing problem in integrating $$ \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\int_{3}^{\frac12}\int_0^1 zx\sin(xy) \,dzdxdy.$$

I have done integration with respect to $z$ but how to integrate further?

Comment: Integrate with respect to $y$ with a substitution $u=xy$.

Comment: I edited your question. Please check if this is the intended meaning?

Comment: @Fabian yes!! This is the actual question.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 yes it's ok but in the end I'm left with 1/2 -1/2cos pi x. While integrating with respect to x do I need to substitute u = pi x ??

Comment: @user4736473 there were another limits, change it to right

Answer (score 0):

What is upper limit of $y$? If $\frac\pi2$ then
$$\int_0^1\,dz\int_0^\frac{\pi}2 dy\int_{\frac13}^{\frac12}zx\sin(xy)dx =\int_0^1\,zdz\cdot\int_{\frac13}^{\frac12}xdx\int_0^\frac{\pi}2 \sin(xy)dy$$$$ = \left.\dfrac{z^2}2\right|_0^1\cdot\int_\frac13^\frac12\left(-\frac1x\right)x\cos xy\biggr|_{y=0}^\frac{\pi}2\,dx = -\dfrac12\int_\frac13^\frac12\left(\cos \frac{\pi}2x-1\right) \,dx = \frac1{2}x\biggr|_\frac13^\frac12 -\dfrac1{\pi}\sin \frac{\pi}2 x\biggr|_\frac13^\frac12 $$$$ = \boxed{\frac1{12}-\frac1{2\pi}(\sqrt2 - 1)}$$

Comment: Ok...  Upper limit is π/2

Answer (score 0):

After integrating with respect to $z$ you can write your integral $(=:J)$ as
$$J={1\over2}\int_3^{1/2}\int_0^{\pi/3} x\>\sin(xy)\>dy\>dx\ .$$
Here the inner integral $(=:J_i)$ computes to
$$J_i=-\cos(xy)\biggr|_{y=0}^{y=\pi/3}=1-\cos{\pi\,x\over3}\ .$$
We therefore obtain
$$J={1\over2}\left(x-{3\over\pi}\sin{\pi\,x\over3}\right)\biggr|_{x=3}^{x=1/2}={1\over2}\left(-{5\over2}-{3\over\pi}\sin{\pi\over6}\right)=-{5\over4}-{3\over4\pi}\ .$$